# HABTM relationships and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a form that lets me create *new blog posts* and I'd like to be able to create *new categories* from the same form.

I have a habtm relationship between posts and categories, which is why I'm having trouble with this.

I have the following 2 models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :category_ids

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories # should this be singular? 
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

My form lets me pick from a bunch of existing categories or create a brand new one.  My form is as follows.

```
# using simple_form gem
.inputs
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :body

  # the line below lets me choose from existing categories
  = f.association :categories, :label => 'Filed Under'

  # I was hoping that the code below would let me create new categories
  = f.fields_for :category do |builder|
    = builder.label :content, "Name"
    = builder.text_field :content
```

When I submit my form, it gets processed but the new category is not created. My command prompt output tells me:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category
```

But, if I add `attr_accessible :category`, I get a big fat crash with error message "unknown attribute: category".

If I change the fields_for target to :categories (instead of category) then my form doesn't even display.

I've spent a while trying to figure this out, and watched the recent railscasts on nested_models and simple_form but couldn't get my problem fixed.

Would this be easier if I was using a has_many :through relationship (with a join model) instead of a habtm?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12961298/1446551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who answered.  After much trial and error, I managed to come up with a fix.

First of all, I switched from a HABTM to a **has_many :through** relationship, calling my join model **categorization.rb** (instead of categorizations_posts.rb) - NB: the fix detailed below will likely work with a HABTM too:

**Step 1: I changed my models to look like this:**

```
# post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :category_ids
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end

#category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, :through => :categorizations
  attr_accessible :name, :post_ids
end

#categorization.rb
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category
end
```

From the post model above: obviously, the accessor named **:category_ids** must be present if you want to enable selecting multiple **existing categories**, but you **do not** need an accessor method for **creating** new categories...  I didn't know that.

**Step 2: I changed my view to look like this:**

```
-# just showing the relevent parts
= fields_for :category do |builder|
  = builder.label :name, "Name"
  = builder.text_field :name
```

From the view code above, it's important to note the use of `fields_for :category` as opposed to the somewhat unintuitive `fields_for :categories_attributes`

**Step 3** 
Finally, I added some code to my controller:

```
# POST /posts
# POST /posts.xml
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @category = @post.categories.build(params[:category]) unless params[:category][:name].blank?
  # stuff removed
end


def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @category = @post.categories.build(params[:category]) unless params[:category][:name].blank?
  # stuff removed
end
```

Now, when I create a new post, I can simultaneously choose multiple existing categories from the select menu **and** create a brand new category at the same time - it's not a case of one-or-the-other

There is one *tiny bug* which **only** occurs when *editing and updating* existing posts; in this case it won't let me simultaneously create a new category **and** select multiple existing categories - if I try to do both at the same time, then only the existing categories are associated with the post, and the brand-new one is rejected (with no error message).  **But** I can get round this by editing the post twice, once to create the new category (which automagically associates it with the post) and then a second time to select some additional existing categories from the menu - like I said this is not a big deal because it all works really well otherwise and my users can adapt to these limits

Anyway, I hope this helps someone.

Amen.

Answer (score 0):

In your form you probably should render the fields_for once per category (you can have multiple categories per post, hence the habtm relation). Try something like:

```
- for category in @post.categories
  = fields_for "post[categories_attributes][#{category.new_record? ? category.object_id : category.id}]", category do |builder|
    = builder.hidden_field :id unless category.new_record?
    = builder.label :content, "Name"
    = builder.text_field :content
```

Comment: nice idea, but no-worky - i got the problem fixed, will post an answer in a few minutes once I've stopped wooting

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm looking forward to see your solution for this…

Answer (score 0):

I have made my application and my nested form works with HABTM.
My model is :

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :profession

    has_and_belongs_to_many :cities

    belongs_to :user

    attr_accessible :city_ids, :cities
    def self.check_city(user,city)

     user.cities.find_by_id(city.id).present?

    end 

end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :city_name

    has_and_belongs_to_many :user_profiles

end
```

In my form I have:

```
-# just showing the relevent parts


= f.fields_for :cities do|city| 

            = city.text_field :city_name
```

And at my controller:

```
 def create

    params[:user_profile][:city_ids] ||= [] 
    if params[:user_profile][:cities][:city_name].present?
      @city= City.create(:city_name=>params[:user_profile][:cities][:city_name])
      @city.save
      params[:user_profile][:city_ids] << @city.id
    end

    @user=current_user
    params[:user_profile].delete(:cities)
    @user_profile = @user.build_user_profile(params[:user_profile])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_profile.save

        format.html { redirect_to @user_profile, notice: 'User profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user_profile, status: :created, location: @user_profile }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user_profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def update

    params[:user_profile][:city_ids] ||= [] 
    if params[:user_profile][:cities][:city_name].present?
      @city= City.create(:city_name=>params[:user_profile][:cities][:city_name])
      @city.save
      params[:user_profile][:city_ids] << @city.id
    end
    @user=current_user
    params[:user_profile].delete(:cities)
    @user_profile = @user.user_profile

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_profile.update_attributes(params[:user_profile])

        format.html { redirect_to @user_profile, notice: 'User profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user_profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This code works.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try it with (not testet):

```
attr_accessible :category_attributes
```

And HBTM relations arent really recommened... But I use them on my own :P

Comment: I've tried this, and also using categories_attributes (both in the model and in the form) and neither work.  Would you recommend using has_many :through instead?  I think I will give that a go now

Comment: Baybe you are faster in solving this problem with non-hbtm :P