# Rails HABTM with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have three tables, accounts, campaigns and accounts_campaigns. I want to have checkboxes for select accounts in the campaigns edit form.

I have Campaign's model like this:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts
end
```

I think i dont need to define the relationship on Account.

And my form is:

```
= hidden_field_tag "campaign[accounts_ids][]", nil
  - Account.all.each do |account|
    %label.checkbox
      = check_box_tag "campaign[accounts_ids][]", account.id, @campaign.account_ids.include?(account.id),
      id: dom_id(account)
      = "#{account.name} - #{account.email}"
```

But i received this error:

```
unknown attribute: accounts_ids
```

Comment: You most certainly need to define the relationship both ways, you cannot just define it in one model. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944542/rails-3-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: I dont understand why i have to add relationsip on account model but anyway, it neither works

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Comment: Finally i got it working without define relationship on both models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally I got it, is not necessary to use has_many :through as many people recomends, this is the easiest setup possible i think to add checkboxes for select items on a HABTM (has and belongs to many, many has many) relationship.

To recapitulate I want to have checkboxes on campaig to select the accounts that campaign will use.

**First**, on the model for the form you want to add the checkboxes

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mail_sequences, order: 'step'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts
end
```

**Second**, There's NO need to create the relationship on the other model (Account)

**Third**, On the form, this is haml,  (this maybe could be optimized):

```
  = hidden_field_tag "campaign[account_ids][]", nil
  - Account.all.each do |account|
    %label.checkbox
      = check_box_tag "campaign[account_ids][]", account.id, @campaign.account_ids.include?(account.id),
      id: dom_id(account)
      = "#{account.name} - #{account.email}"
```

Comment: The haml is not the problem, the code is `campaign[account_ids][]`, `@campaign.account_ids.include?(account.id)`