# model breaking on accepts_nested_attributes_for with no association error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I've got a `Wine` model, and a wine can have many `Varietals`.

I have a `WineVarietals` model and join the Wines to Varietals through that table.

When I put `accepts_nested_attributes_for :wine_varietals` in my model, I get
`No association found for name`wine_varietals'. Has it been defined yet?`

But I do have the association in my model.

My Wine model is

```
class Wine < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :winery_id, :wine_varietals_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :wine_varietals

    belongs_to :winery
    has_many :wine_varietals
    #has_and_belongs_to_many :varietals, :join_table => :wine_varietals
    has_many :wine_photos
    has_many :vintages
```

I also have WineVarietal and Varietal models.

If I comment out the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` line, the error goes away.

I've tried different forms of pluralization `wines_varietals`, `wine_varietal` but can't seem to get rid of this error.

Comment: Please have a look on the link below: <br />
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995576/habtm-relationships-and-accepts-nested-attributes-for][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995576/habtm-relationships-and-accepts-nested-attributes-for

Comment: Please have a look on the link below: <br /> 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995576/habtm-relationships-and-accepts-nested-attributes-for][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995576/habtm-relationships-and-accepts-nested-attributes-for

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the line `accepts_nested_attributes_for :wine_varietals` below the `has_many :wine_varietals`

Comment: thanks @Siddick. I had no idea the order was important. I thought I had always seen accepts_nested_attributes_for up top after attr_accessible.

Comment: Thanks! I had such problem, when i defined `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in model concern and included this concern below the has_many association in model class =)